# How to start kubernetes without "minikube start" command everytime?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I'm using windows and I facing a big problem with running Kubernetes.

Each time I want to start Kubernetes must I run this command `minikube start` and it takes a very long time after that must I run this command `minikube dashboard` it's taking too much time.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As you know `minikube` is a single node K8S cluster for development/demo purposes.

You can have a script that will start `minikube` if it's not started or use another tool instead of `minikube` which will load faster.

#### Script for starting minikube

- here is a script I wrote a few years back (just update the minikube version to suit your needs)
  https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/blob/master/scripts/startMinikube.sh

#### Other tool that you can use

- [K3S](https://k3s.io/)
- [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/)
- [Rancher](https://rancher.com/)